# Using "broken" junction link to block writes

Tags: ssd, symbolic-link, cache, spotify, junction

So I wanted to stop Spotify from caching to my SSD (I have a small 60 GB drive), but apparently it's not possible to disable caching.

Spotify keeps the cache in the `%LocalAppData%\Spotify\Data` folder. So I just wrote a junction link and linked the cache location to a source folder that doesn't exist. The link remains and the folder is not accessible. Spotify doesn't seem to mind and works without any issues (and more importantly, without caching to the drive).

My question is if this is a viable method to block access to a folder. Could there be any downsides to this? And also is there a better way to do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there should be no problem.

Any attempt to open a file at an invalid path will result in a broken handle (and actually not opening anything). So Spotify will keep getting error messages from the system when opening caches, and perhaps the dev team have chosen to ignore that.